# React-native issue getting imageUri out of an array with a for Loop

Tags: arrays, react-native

I'm trying to get for each imageUri in the products array the value.
After which is encoded in Base64 and stocked in the const "bloc".
default place of stocking images + bloc gives a string uri of the image.

I stock the concatenated data into the variable img and pass it to the product list.

The product list is made of divs to be able to pdf the data.
my console in the logs EditDocument.jsx  look like this:

```js
console.log("ED IMG2:", img);
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
 console.log("ED IMGS:", img.imageUri);
}
```

> `ED IMG2: Array [
> undefined,
> undefined,
> undefined,
> ]
> ED IMGS: Array [
> undefined,
> undefined,
> undefined,
> ]

my console logs in ProductList.jsx:
console.log("PROD LIST IMG:", img),

> PROD LIST IMG: Array [
> undefined,
> undefined,
> undefined,
> ]

EditDocument.jsx :

```
let img = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data?.products?.length; i++) {
  try {
    if (data?.products) {
      const bloc = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(data.products.imageUri, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      })
      img = "data:image/png;base64," + bloc;

      console.log("ED IMG:", img);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  }
  img.push(img[i]);
  }


  console.log("ED IMG2:", img);
  for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    console.log("ED IMGS:", img.imageUri);
  }
```

> ED IMG2: Array [
> undefined,
> undefined,
> undefined,
> ]

ProductList.jsx :

```js
const ProductList = ({ products, language, img }) => {

    return (
     console.log("PROD LIST IMG:", img),
    <>
      <div style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: 30 }}>
      <div className="tr">
        <div className="th col1">#</div>
        <div className="th col2">{t("PRODUCT", { lng: language })}</div>
        <div className="th col3">{t("DESCRIPTION", { lng: language })}</div>
        <div className="th col4">{t("N°", { lng: language })}</div>
        <div className="th col5">{t("PRICE", { lng: language })}</div>
        <div className="th col6">{t("VAT", { lng: language })}</div>
        <div className="th col7">{t("TOTAL", { lng: language })}</div>
      </div>
      
      {products?.map((product, index) => (
        console.log("PROD LIST IMG:", img),
        <div key={index} className="tr no-break">
          {/* <div className="td col1">{index + 1}</div> */}
          {img ? (
            console.log("PROD2 LIST IMG:", img.length),
            img.map(function (imageUri, index) {
              return (
                <div key={index} className="td col1">
                  <img src={imageUri} style={styles.image} />
                </div>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <div className="td col1">{index + 1}</div>
          )}
          
          <div className="td col2">{product.name}</div>
```

Comment: If you're using divs, you're using React and not React Native - is that correct?

Comment: I'm using DIVs to be able to pdf the document afterwards

Comment: Console log of products looks like this:   "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "58",
        "name": "123",
        "imageUri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%4501",
      },
      {
        "name": "1234",
        "imageUri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fcomagenda-ea12d759-6ce0-4210",
        "option": false
      }
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

When doing async operations on an array type of useState `Promise.all` is your friend.

```js
export const getData = async (limit=10,skip=5) => {
  const data = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=${limit}&skip=${skip}`);
  const json = await data.json();
  const colors = colorGenerator(limit)
  const products = await Promise.all(
    json.products.map(async (product,i) => {
      // strip unnecessary data
      const { thumbnail, images, stock, ...item } = product;
      return {
        ...item,
        imageUri,
        color:colors[i]
      };
    })
  );
  return products
};
```

For a more fleshed out example see [here](https://snack.expo.dev/T8fSIMxtM)

Comment: @ PhantomSpooks, This is for sure a great way to work it out when working with json files. Now my Uris are saved on the mobile device and I can get the first imageUri if I use the [0] after products with exactly the same function. My issue stays in the loop result , I'd like to get all images in this array, for the moment the content is always empty or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue like this:

```
  let imgs = [];
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < data?.products?.length; i++) {
    if (data?.products[i]?.imageUri) {
      const bloc = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(data.products[i]?.imageUri, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      })
      imgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${bloc}`)
    }
  }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Thanks for all answers,